# How can I deploy my database from SQL Server 2008 Express to Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am using Visual Studio Community 2013, SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition for an MVC web application using entity framework code first migrations for my database.

I am trying to get my local application hosted on the Microsoft Azure platform.

I have registered for a trial account which expires in 30 days, and deployed my MVC5 app out which has been successful.

However, this app requires a database which I am struggling to deploy.

What is the easiest way to get my database deployed out to Azure as I do not seem to have the :

"Tasks" -> "Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database" option available to me in SSMS.

I have extracted a Data-tier Application of my local database and have it stored on my C drive, however if I connect to my Azure Account in a second window, and right click the server then select Deploy Data-tier Application, it fails on "Creating schema object in database" with the following error:

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Users cannot be mapped to certificates, asymmetric keys, or Windows
>   logins in this version of SQL Server. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:
>   40528)

I'm assuming its tried to create my local account plus the `IIS APPPOOL` account I had to set up to host the website on my local network, however I do not see a way of removing them from the `.dacpac` export.

When I refresh the Databases node, there is still no database, I'm fairly lost now as to how I might get my db deployed to this server?

Comment: Have you checked out the [migration documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate/)? There are a couple of tools listed there, including the [Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) which may be able to help you with migrating to Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can extract a compatible Data-tier application and then Deploy it to your target server using your current version of Management studio, then this approach should work, see this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate/) for more reading on ensuring your database is compatible.

Failing this, as was in my case. I [downloaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx) Management Studio 2015, which gave me the option to deploy database to Azure by simply right clicking the required database.

Again, this threw up the error regarding my database level `IISAPPOOL` user, but not my server account user. As a way around this, I took a backup/restore of the database and removed this user then deployed the copy database obviously minus the problem account.

Now all that was left to do was add a transform to my Release `web.config` with the Azure connection string as provided on the Azure dashboard, and re-deploy the website.

Problem solved.